# Heap size for Rust programs very large when measured with valgrind using massif

Tags: rust, valgrind, massif

I'm trying to measure the memory size of a rust program I'm writing. I noticed that when I measure the heap size with the command:

`valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes ./program`

And measure using ms_print, that the memory size was quite large (intially around 16MB). Eventually, I reduced my rust program to an empty main function:

```rust
fn main() {
}
```

And I compiled, and *still* had 16MB as my memory size. I noticed that when I used a different machine, the very same binary would be 4MB in total size. One of my friends tried this with the same program on his machine, with the same rust/valgrind version and got 4MB of size as well.

I imagine this is some sort of pre-allocation to memory that might be used in the heap, but I can't figure out any way to control it. I even tried changing my allocator following [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/platform-and-target-support/global-allocators.html) guide, but nothing changed.

System details:

```
OS version       = Ubuntu 18.04
valgrind version = valgrind-3.13.0
cargo version    = cargo 1.39.0-nightly (3f700ec43 2019-08-19)
rustc version    = rustc 1.39.0-nightly (e44fdf979 2019-08-21)
ms_print         = ms_print-3.13.0
libc version     = ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
```

Comment: That probably output input of stdout, stdin and stderr. That also possible that rust need allocation to parse `argv` from the command line. And maybe opther thing. Why bother of such thing ? this is only at startup and is fast enough.

Comment: @Stargateur It seems that this isn't due to stdin, stdout, stderr and argv as the same program gives a different output on different computers. I think it's highly unlikely that that would consume 16MB of memory as well.

As for why bother, the goal was to write a program that consumes little memory but still has good performance, i.e. if the target machine has a very small amount of memory (say an old phone, or an Arduino), memory is a precious resource and can't be wasted! Hence the importance of checking memory usage. I believe the response below provides a good answer!

Comment: I maintain my claim as Sébastien said have a page of 16mo doesn't mean the program really use 16mo. Please consider test your program with [no_std](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/intro/no-std.html)

Comment: You need to check __effective__ memory usage. Checking how much was allocated isn't a good resource outside of programs running on bare metal without virtual page support or without an MMU entirely (and in that case they'll be equal).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The place that is leading you in error is `pages-as-heap`, due to a misconception in how page management on most modern operating systems, particularly linux, works. This **will not be true for all platforms** and depends on the allocator, the underlying platform and the MMU. In practice, if you platform supports virtual memory, you'll most likely have something like this.

A page is not always a **forcibly reserved** area in memory. Most memory functions (`mmap`, `malloc` and a few others) will allocate memory, but this will only be considered indicative by the operating system/kernel. You can convince yourself of this with the following test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *ptr = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
  sleep(100);
  return 0;
}
```

Run it a few times, and...

```
:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15930        1716        5553         170        8661       13752
Swap:             0           0           0
:~# ./hog &
[1] 27577
...
[99] 27674
:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15930        1717        5552         170        8661       13751
Swap:             0           0           0
```

You can replicate this test in `rust`, but you need to go slightly further down than you'd normally go in abstractions to achieve this:

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut vec:Vec<u8> = vec![];
  vec.reserve(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
}
```

Memory only matters once it is **initialized** and **accessed**. At that point, the OS knows you actually want it, and allocates it all the way down to hardware. Rust is no exception to this - until you're using some of that heap, that heap is just a `mmap` in the kernel pointing to virtual memory.

As such, by using the `pages-as-heap` argument, you are only looking for the "potential" memory before any reallocations are done, not the *actual* memory used. Remove this parameter and you'll see your program consume 300 or so bytes of heap (which you can easily analyze with `valgrind` itself).

The reason your friends are seeing a different output is because their page size is 4kB and yours is 16kB. I'll track down the exact point in the rustc source code later - rust allocates 1024 pages.